# Updating innerHTML on API event

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml, pusher

I have a websocket open with the Pusher API and whenever a new user subscribes or unsubscribes to the channel it is successfully updating the `members.count` variable when I check in the console.

However, the `innerHTML` is only displayed on load. **It is not being updated.**

```
  var presenceChannel = pusher.subscribe('presence-channel')
  var userCount

  presenceChannel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members){
      userCount = members.count;
      document.getElementById('userCount').innerHTML = userCount;
  });
```

html

```
<h1 id="userCount">X</h1>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show an HTML snippet?  it might be that you want to use `.val()` rather than `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Thanks!  Have you tried putting a breaking on the `userCount = members.count;` line to make sure it is being hit?

Comment: Nope, what is a breaking and how do I try it out? @phoenixblade9

Comment: @propster Either use your browser dev tools to set a 'breakpoint' on that line of code, or just add a `console.log('here')` above it and see if that message appears in the console

Comment: Take a look here on how to set a break point in firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger

Comment: @Phoenixblade9 `console.log( userCount = members.count; ` only prints it on load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used pusher before, but a quick glance at the docs implies that `pusher:subscription_succeeded` fires only once... ironically when the subscribe() succeeds.  I think you want  `pusher:member_added` and `pusher:member_removed` for when members come and leave.

I would create a method to handle it all:

```
var presenceChannel = pusher.subscribe('presence-channel');

function updateUserCount() {
  document.getElementById('userCount').innerHTML = presenceChannel.members.count;
}

presenceChannel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
  updateUserCount();
});
presenceChannel.bind('pusher:member_added', function(member) {
  updateUserCount();
});
presenceChannel.bind('pusher:member_removed', function(member) {
  updateUserCount();
});
```

Comment: This works. Pusher should streamline the function tho.

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward to me.  `subscription_succeeded` means you connected to the socket successfully.  Ideally you wouldn't even bind the member added/removed events until the subscription has been established successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably an issue of innerHTML not being cool with that type... as a dirty hack until I find the right answer, try:

```
document.getElementById('userCount').innerHTML = "" + userCount;
```